# Responsive Text in between column in a row

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am making an application with angular and bootstrap and i am given the requirement that i need to place a link between two columns in the 3rd row of iteration.

My current try is as follows:

**Html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6" *ngFor="let data of suggestions">
            <div class="data-wrapper">
                {{ data.id }}
                <br>
                {{ data.name }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="middle-text-link"> Click here to go to link </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.data-wrapper {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.middle-text-link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 25%;
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

**Working Demo :**  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-dr8t57

Here i have used the above css properties to achieve the scenario of placing the link in between columns but it is not responsive.

Kindly help me how to achieve the scenario of placing a link text in between two columns in third row which needs to be responsive.

Comment: Please check the below code. It works. Tested in  my local system and yes, it's responsive too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Transform to center

```
.middle-text-link {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%); 
   background-color: red;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 15px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just tweaked your CSS by applying `top:50%;left:50%;transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` to align it to horizontal and vertical center. Make sure that parent element `class="container parent"` is `relative`. 
so your CSS can be in this way

```
.parent{
  position: relative;
}
.middle-text-link {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%); 
   background-color: red;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 15px; 
}
```